# Build Repast Models via CLI

Tags: java, command-line-interface, repast-simphony

I am currently looking for a way to build Repast models via CLI and then start the model with the batch-runner. Later the process is supposed to be automatically executed within a CI/CD pipeline. Therefore the building process should be executed independent from Eclipse.

I have already tried the Java compiler and the Groovy compiler which had issues locating the Repast specific classes. Currently, it only works via CLI with the Equinox launcher within Eclipse and only when the model is in an Eclipse workspace. However, the model needs to be built independently of Eclipse.

Does anyone perhaps have an idea about the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be possible with pure Java Repast Simphony projects, e.g., JZombies. You will need to specify a workspace where the project exists and issue the following:

```
<path/to/eclipse/>eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild -data "<path/to/workspace>"
```

We're looking into how to successfully do this with Repast Simphony projects that invoke additional builders (e.g., Statechart, ReLogo).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has the option to export an Ant `build.xml` file without the Eclipse compiler from the Project. You still need a subset of the `JAR`s and Libs in the Eclipse plugins folder, but this allows to build and even execute the GUI without having Eclipse installed.